# How does a site like sizzy.co access localhost on my machine

Tags: javascript

How can a website access a local server I'm running on my machine? Can someone give a basic example of how to display my local site inside of an external site?

Comment: Did you try reading the FAQ? It explains what is going on. http://sizzy.co/faq

Comment: Looks like it just uses an iframe. As long as your browser can resolve the `src` attribute of the iframe and the headers allow embedding then it'll work fine.

Comment: Yes i read the faq. Did you? It doesnt say anything about how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is a valid hostname, so `<iframe src="http://localhost">` will work; it effectively means "load whatever web server is running on the computer that is currently displaying this frame".

It won't show *your* localhost to the user, though. It'll show the *user's* localhost (if they have one).  If you want your local site to appear in an external site, you'll need to refer to it by your public IP address (assuming you have a static IP address) and keep your computer on 24/7; or put your code on a real server.

(To expand on this:  localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1, which is the IP address version of "myself".  Importantly, this resolution is performed by the client, not the server -- this is why it ends up pointing to the end user's localhost, not the server's localhost.)

Comment: This is what confuses me. Why doesn't the iframe look for localhost:8080 on its own server. How is it resolving my localhost?

Comment: I understand the confusion; I'll try to think of better wording for the answer...   it boils down to: the computer doing the browsing is the one that resolves "localhost", not the server.

Comment: Thanks. I marked your answer as correct because I just tested and the iframe in fact showed my local server.